# mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini

Tags: php, email

Yes I know this might be 100th duplicate of this question, but I looked over this thread:  [How to configure XAMPP to send mail from localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost) and many others and still can't get it to work. My classmate did the same thing earlier today and it all works fine for him. I even asked for his .ini files and code, it still doesn't work. I also reinstalled xampp to see if that would fix it and it doesn't.

**php.ini:**

```
[mail function]

SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
sendmail_from = maill@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe" -t"
```

**sendmail.ini**

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
smtp_ssl=ssl
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=maill@gmail.com
auth_password=magicalpwd
force_sender=galerijospastas@gmail.com
```

This project will never go live, everything works from my machine with xampp help.
Same applies to my classmate, yet for him it works, what am I missing?

Comment: you have port 587 setup, how come you got error on port 25? is there anything else?

Comment: may be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532486/failed-to-connect-to-mailserver-at-localhost-port-25) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334250/warning-mail-function-mail-failed-to-connect-to-mailserver-at-localhost/2334290) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21836282/php-function-mail-isnt-working) can help.

Comment: You're missing the backslash between `exe` and `"`

Comment: `sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"`

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```